# WPF Datagrid MouseBinding MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I managed to handle a double click on one of my datagrid rows to execute a command on my viewmodel by this xaml:

[image]

This works perfect when I click somewhere in the area of the first column (which is bound to the readonly ID), but fails when the double click is done in the area of the textbox in column two (CustomerNumber, which of course catches the doubleclick).

Which would be a MVVM-like way to handle doubleclicks for both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and add a `MouseBinding` to the `TextBox` in the `CellEditingTemplate`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Customer Number">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerNumber}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerNumber}">
                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.EditCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                </TextBox.InputBindings>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```