# WPF C# MouseBinding for TextBlock for the whole length of block

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I would like to use MouseBinding for TextBlock in my WPF application.
Although I have found [WPF Datagrid MouseBinding MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583835/wpf-datagrid-mousebinding-mvvm) and that works.

My problem is when I do a double mouse click on TextBlock which does not contain a string it's not working (check screenshot).
Is there any solution for that?

Xaml Code

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding SayHello}"/>
                </TextBlock.InputBindings>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBClV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achiev this by setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` and / or `VerticalContentAlignment` at your `ListView` like

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

See [the microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment?view=netcore-3.1) for more info.